# No output from ncurses without second getch

Tags: c, ncurses

I am having a similar problem to [Ncurses No Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135225/ncurses-no-output).
Just I am having a `getch` call before exiting.
I don't see any output when I don't add a second `getch` call
before outputting anything. The following is a collection of
all relevant code parts copied together in one routine
exhibiting the same problem as my complete program.
So some calls look superfluous but I find those necessary
in the local context.

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define bool ncbool
#include <ncurses.h>
#undef bool


gint32 main ( gint32 argc, gchar * argv [] )
{
    initscr ();
    keypad ( stdscr, FALSE );
    nonl ();
    cbreak ();
    nodelay ( stdscr, FALSE );
    noecho ();

    /*
    gint zch_extra;
    zch_extra = getch ();
    */

    WINDOW* w;
    w = newwin ( 5, 10, 3, 3 );
    box ( w, 0, 0 );
    wnoutrefresh ( w );

    mvwaddstr ( w, 1, 1, "huhu" );
    wnoutrefresh ( w );
    doupdate ();

    mvwaddstr ( w, 2, 1, "<cont>" );
    wrefresh ( w );

    gint zch;
    zch = getch ();

    clear ();
    refresh ();

    nl ();
    nocbreak ();
    echo ();

    endwin ();

    return 1;
}
```

I only see output when I add the extra `getch` commented out in the code.

Compilation commands:

```
gcc -I /usr/include/ncurses -I /home/mkiever/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -ansi -ggdb -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -o test main.o -lncurses `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

Platform (`uname -a`): `Linux Pirx 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) i686 GNU/Linux`

What am I doing wrong? I guess, it's my combination of different `refresh` calls, but I don't have a clue where exactly the problem is.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: btw, `main` returns `int`, and the argument `argc` is an `int` too; using `gint32` instead can never be "more correct"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Possibly gone a bit too far using GLib, true that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curses starts up wanting to clear the screen *stdscr* (as noted in the manual page for [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr)):

> **`initscr`** also causes the
>          first call to [refresh(3x)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html) to clear the screen.

Doing that requires a refresh, sometime after the call to `initscr`.  getch does a refresh of *stdscr*.  In the non-working case, the program creates, modifies and refreshes the other window, but when you call getch, curses refreshes *stdscr* (again, in the [manual](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters)), overwriting that window.

It does those steps internally, no need to show the result until the program requests input via `getch`.

Comment: The `initscr` man page says "initscr also causes the first call to refresh(3x) to clear the screen". I always read this as, it is doing this, not as, I need to do this. Still confused, but if I replace the first `getch` by `refresh` everything works.

Comment: sure: `getch` calls `refresh`.

Comment: Why is the `refresh` from `initscr` not sufficient? Or is there none? There's nothing happening between this and the first `getch`.

Comment: `initscr` doesn't ***do*** a `refresh`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience :-)  Finally got the meaning of the docs. "`initscr` makes the first call to `refresh` necessary" - got it.